# Jenkins Job stuck in Uploading dSYM to Crittercism

Tags: jenkins, crittercism

My Jenkins Job worked well, however, recently it usually stuck in

```
09:10:02 Archiving artifacts
09:10:05 Uploading dSYM to Crittercism...
09:10:06 /home/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/JobName/builds/23/archive/build/artifacts/Glip-dSYM.zip
Loading .....
```

It always loading. And I can't stop it unless reboot my Jenkins master server.
My question is
 
1. How can I stop it unless reboot server?

2. How solve this problem always loading problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using Jenkins plugin to upload dSYM which is developed by a third party developer. You may refer to its documentation to see if it helps you :

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Crittercism+dSYM+Plugin

Otherwise, post a comment underneath it as this seems to be related to Jenkins job and not Apteligent.